# PHP search values from multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have two arrays as following:

```
$price = [
    34 => 65.00,
    35 => 95.00,
    36 => 125.00,
];

$dbPrices = [
    36 => [
        'sales_price' => 125.00,
        'our_price' => 0.00
    ],
    35 => [
        'sales_price' => 98.00,
        'our_price' => 0.00
    ],
    34 => [
        'sales_price' => 70.00,
        'our_price' => 65.00
   ]
];
```

What I really want to find out if the values in the `$price` array are exist in the second array. It this case it can be check either `sales_price` or `our_price` contains the value from the `$price` array.

If those values in the `$price` array cannot be found in the second array, a new array must be created from those values.

So, new array should be as follow:

```
$newPrices = [35 => 95]
```

This is how I tried it. $dbPrices is my second array:

```
$discountItems = [];
$discountItems = array_intersect_key($price, $dbPrices);

$filter = function($v,$k) use($dbPrices){
return array_values($dbPrices[$k]) != $v;
};

$newPrices = array_filter($discountItems, $filter, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH );
```

It doesn't work in this way. Can anybody help me regarding this?

Comment: Can you provide us with $price and $dbPrices hard-coded to the values you're showing us rather than showing us a print_r so we can quickly and easier run your code and see what it's doing?

Comment: @KevinY, Updated my question accordingly your comment

Comment: Please _properly_ explain what exactly _"exist in the second array or not"_ is supposed to mean.

Comment: @CBroe That means I really want to find out if the values in the price array are exist in the second array. If those values in the price array cannot be found in the second array, a new array must be created from those values.

Comment: So you want to check if either `sales_price` or `our_price` contains the value from the first array, yes?

Comment: @CBroe Yes it can check either `sales_price` or `our_price` of second array

Comment: Not sure what you'd need array_intersect for, `$newPrices = array_filter($price, function($price, $id) use ($dbPrices) { return $price != $dbPrices[$id]['sales_price'] && $price != $dbPrices[$id]['our_price']; }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH);` does the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Your filter logic is currently comparing an array to a number. I believe the solution you're looking for may be as simple as utilizing `in_array`:

```
<?php

$price = [
    34 => 65.00,
    35 => 95.00,
    36 => 125.00,
];

$dbPrices = [
    36 => [
        'sales_price' => 125.00,
        'our_price' => 0.00
    ],
    35 => [
        'sales_price' => 98.00,
        'our_price' => 0.00
    ],
    34 => [
        'sales_price' => 70.00,
        'our_price' => 65.00
    ]
];


$discountItems = [];
$discountItems = array_intersect_key($price, $dbPrices);

$filter = function($v,$k) use($dbPrices){
    return !in_array($v, array_values($dbPrices[$k]));
};

$newPrices = array_filter($discountItems, $filter, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH );

print_r($newPrices);
```

The output:

> Array
> (
> [35] => 95
> )

Answer (score 1):

You can use foreach and compaire $price array with $dbPrices using it's key. if sales_price or our_price match then loop continue else store $price array value which not match in $dbPrices array. try below code.

```
 <?php
        $price = [
            34 => 65.00,
            35 => 95.00,
            36 => 125.00,
        ];
        
        $dbPrices = [
            '36' => [
                'sales_price' => 125.00,
                'our_price' => 0.00
            ],
            '35' => [
                'sales_price' => 98.00,
                'our_price' => 0.00
            ],
            '34' => [
                'sales_price' => 70.00,
                'our_price' => 65.00
           ]
        ];
        
        $newPrices = [];
        foreach($dbPrices as $key => $value ) {
            if ($price[$key] == $value['sales_price'] || $price[$key] == $value['our_price']) {
                continue;   
            }else{
                $newPrices[$key] = $price[$key];
            }
        }
    
    print_r($newPrices);
    ?>
```